# Working with hdf files in Databricks cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, cluster-computing, hdf

I am trying to create a simple .hdf in the Databricks environment. I can create the file on the driver, but the same code when executed with rdd.map(), it throws following exception.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 287.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 287.0 (TID 1080) (10.67.238.26 executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: **'RuntimeError: Can't decrement id ref count (file write failed:** time = Tue Nov  1 11:38:44 2022
, filename = '/dbfs/mnt/demo.hdf', file descriptor = 7, errno = 95, error message = '**Operation not supported**', buf = 0x30ab998, total write size = 40, bytes this sub-write = 40, bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 0)', from <command-1134257524229717>, line 13. Full traceback below:
```

I can write the same file on the worker and copy the file back to /dbfs/mnt. However, I was looking for a way through which I can write/modify the .hdf files stored in dbfs/mnt locaction through worker nodes directly.

```
def create_hdf_file_tmp(x):
    import numpy as np
    import h5py, os, subprocess
    import pandas as pd
 
    dummy_data = [1,2,3,4,5]
    df_data = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data, columns=['Numbers'])

    with h5py.File('/dbfs/mnt/demo.hdf', 'w') as f:
        dset = f.create_dataset('default', data = df_data) # write to .hdf file
    
    return True

def read_hdf_file(file_name, dname):
    import numpy as np
    import h5py, os, subprocess
    import pandas as pd

    with h5py.File(file_name, 'r') as f:
        data = f[dname]
        print(data[:5])    
    return data


#driver code
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['/dbfs/mnt/demo.hdf'])
result = rdd.map(lambda x: create_hdf_file_tmp(x)).collect()
```

Above is the minimal code that I am trying to run in the Databricsk notebook with 1 driver and 2 worker nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From error message: `Operation not supported`, most probably, when writing HDF file, the API uses something like random writes that aren't supported by DBFS (see [DBFS Local API limitations in the docs](https://docs.databricks.com/files/index.html#local-file-api-limitations)).  You will need to write a file to a local disk and then move that file to DBFS mount.  But it will work only on the driver node...

Comment: Yea, you are correct, dbfs doesn't allow random writes. Modifying the files locally and moving to dbfs solved the issue. Appreciate your efforts.